# Order of intermediate operations in Java Stream pipeline

Tags: java, java-stream

The order of the intermiediate operations is not being followed. I have code snippet below

```
     Integer[] arr = {5,4,3,2,7,8,9,0,6};
     List<Integer> lst = Stream.of(arr)
    .filter(e -> (e % 2) == 0)
    .peek(System.out::println) 
    .limit(3)              
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

output is

```
     4
     2
     8
```

Since peek(System.out::println) is applied before limit, I expected it to print all even numbers and after that it should apply limit and get list of 3 items.

Why is that it println is called for 3 items only. Should the order of my functions on stream not matter ?